# Raw buffer returned by fs.readFile not converting certain characters to decimal values properly

Tags: node.js, websocket, fs, gltf

I have some data in a .glb file that starts off like this:

glTF   ¤Ö @  JSON

I read the file using this code:

```
fs.readFile(file,  (err, data) => {

    if (err) console.log(err);

    var message = {
        "Message": "glb_string",
        "Item": data
    }
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(message));
});
```

And send it off using a websocket connection to a client websocket server.

However, the Node buffer returned by fs.readFile looks like this:

```
Buffer@0x0000020A2BF455D0 67 6c 54 46 02 00 00 00 a4 d6 01 00 40 08 00 00 4a 53 4f 4e 7b ...
```

These values are incorrect. It gets simple letters correct in utf-8 form:

```
g(67) l(6c) T(54) F(46)
```

But once it gets to special characters like ¤ and Ö the buffer returns 00. The buffer should look like this:

```
Buffer@0x000001DD07B0E590 67 6C 54 46 02 20 20 20 C2 A4 C3 ...
```

or in decimal form:

```
103 108 84 70 2 32 32 32 164 214 1 32 64 8 32 32 74 83 79 78

2 is "stx start of text ctrl-b"
1 is "soh start of heading ctrl-a"
164 is ¤ 
214 is Ö
```

Not sure why the raw buffer that is being returned does not use the right values for those special characters. As a result the .glb file is not usable.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: might be a dumb question, but have you checked your file with a hex editor? i just tried it using your sample string, and i get exactly the same results when i view the hex of the file via `xxd` (linux command line) as with `fs.readFile`

Comment: I haven't tried that, what I did was put the string into this website: https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/

Comment: The real reason behind all this is that I'm trying to transfer a .glb file, which is a binary gltf file, across a websocket connection intact. To do that, I have to read the .glb file, send it via JSON.stringify, then decode it on the client-side. So far I haven't been able to encode the .glb server side, send it to the client via websocket, then decode it client-side and keep the .glb file working. The .glb file that results on the client is not usable by gltf viewers.

Comment: Hmm, you are right that the hex editor looks the exact same as fs.readFile. I think the reason my code isn't working is because the .glb file specification requires a 12 byte header, which the converter isn't accounting for.